# Accessing child data from parent pointer

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say that I have a parent class that I cannot change and it has a function that will be used by the children. The two children are similar but use different kinds of data. Let's say for this example that one contains an array with associated methods and the other contains a 2d array with associated methods.

```
struct Parent {
    Parent* DoSomethingWithChildren(Parent &other)
};

struct Child1 : Parent {
   int a[x];
};

struct Child2 : Parent {
   int b[x][y];
};
```

Now let's say that I create two children.

```
Parent* child1 = new Child1();
Parent* child2 = new Child2();

child1.DoSomethingWithChildren(child2);
```

The DoSomethingWithChildren function should be able to access child1 using the 'this' pointer if I'm not mistaken and since child2 is passed to the function it should also be accessible.

The problem is that within the DoSomeThingWithChildren function I'm only able to access data and functions from the parent.

Is there some way to do this? Maybe using templates?

Comment: First of all, your naming conventions are awful. Name them like `Node` and ChildNode` or something like `RootNode` and `Node`, becouse `Parent* child = new Child();` looks just... bad.

Comment: You probably want to override `DoSomethingWithChildren` in each of the Child classes; though I suspect the example provided is too abstract. What you intend to do with the children should influence the design of that function. Is the function recursive?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using generic names for the purpose of this question. In my actual code they have more descriptive names. To cmbasnett: I'm implementing the function in the parent myself. I just can't change the signature.

Comment: Anything can be forced, but instead go with the flow: **redesign**.

Comment: I'm forbidden from changing the parent class. It's a school assignment. This assignment was published after lectures on templates and friend classes so I was hoping that ones of those might be the solution.

Comment: It's hard to help someone when you have like no way of being creative. Post assignment and we'll see.

Comment: If you cannot change the parent class, then what `DoSomethingWithChildren` does in the parent class is fixed and unchanging, as the body of methods are part of a class.  So why are you asking about `DoSomethingWithChildren` and what to do in there?  What you are doing is asking others to read tea leaves based off your half-understood assignment specifications.

Comment: Where you have your pointer to your derived class the notation is wrong, you should have child1->DoSomethingWithChild( child2 ) instead of the dot operator. You have declared dynamic memory using a pointer and you need the -> operator here.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple solutions to your problem.

**Dynamic cast**

```
class Parent {
    public:
        Parent* DoSomethingWithChildren(Parent& other) {
            Child* childPointer = dynamic_cast<Child>(&other);
            if(childPointer) {
                // now you have Child class API
            } else {
                // this was clearly not a Child object
            }
        }
};
```

**Virtual Methods**
Just look them up ;)

---

But mainly i think your concept is wrong. It would be better to do something like that:

```
class Parent {
    virtual void doSomethingWithParent(Parent* parent) = 0;
};

class Child1 : public Parent {
    void doSomethingWithParent(Parent* parent) {
        //you now have Child1 API and parent object
    }
};

int main() {
    Parent parent;
    Child1 child;
    Child2 child2;

    child1.doSomethingWithParent(parent);
    child2.doSomethingWithParent(parent);
}
```

That way each child might have diffrent overload.

Derived classes should implement specifics, not base classes to manage all derived ones. This is simply poor desing.

Comment: Common idiom : `if(Child* childPointer = dynamic_cast<Child>(&other)) {...}`

Comment: Yes, but it might be less newbie-friendly so i posted extended version. But nice to mention it. :)

Comment: Let's say that I have misunderstood the assignment and that I can actually change the parent's method to virtual. How would I access the other child's data in the parent function? I should be able to pass either child1 or child2 to the DoSomeThingWithParent function.

Comment: Do you have constant number of child versions? Do you have constant number of possibilities of data that can be held by child? Which is smaller? There are many factors when desining this kind of architecture. If first answer is true, then you might simply try dynamic-casting to every other type. There might be better ways, but not knowing the assignment i can't foresee what would be better. Best way would be to post content of your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a pointer to the base class and creating new memory when using the constructor for one of its inherited classes. When you call the function that belongs to the base class to do something with one of its derived classes where that derived class has access to the base class's protected or public member variables and functions, the compiler may not know which type to work on explicitly. If you know exactly how many different derived types you will have then within your base class you can have a public enumeration of each type and store this as a private member. Here is an example:

```
class Node {
public:
    enum TYPE {
      TYPE_ONE,
      TYPE_TWO,
    };

private:
    TYPE m_type;

public:
    explicit Node( Node::TYPE type ) : m_type( type ) {}

    Node* doSomeWork( Node* other );
}; // Node

Node* Node::doSomeWork( Node* other ) {        
    Node* pNode = dynamic_cast<Node*>( other );

    switch ( m_type ) {
        case TYPE_ONE: {

            // Do Work Here
            return pNode;
        }
        case TYPE_TWO: {

            // Do Work Here
            return pNode;
        }
        default: {
            // If derived type not defined either throw exception
            // or return a nullptr
            return pNode = nullptr;
        }
    }
}

class Type1 : public Node {
    // Member Variables Here

public:
    Type1() : Node( TYPE_ONE ) {}
};

class Type1 : public Node {
    // Member Variables Here

public:
    Type2() : Node( TYPE_TWO ) {}
};
```

With this example, when you call your function to do the work it will make a decision based on the TYPE and the pointer to the derived type is casted to a pointer of the base type work is done then the pointer is returned.

This will work if you know exactly how many derived types you have. If the amount of derived types is unknown then I would suggest having the doWork function declared as purely virtual within the base class making the base class an abstract class where you can not create an instance of it, and any derived class must implement that purely virtual function and you can have each class override it.

```
class Node {
public:
    virtual ~Node(){}
    virtual Node* doSomeWork( Node* other ) = 0;  

protected:
    Node(){}
};

class Type1 : public Node {
public:
    // Must Be Implemented But Can Be Override
    Node* doSomeWork( Node* other ) override;       
};

class Type2 : public Node {
public:
    // Must Be Implemented But Can Be Override
    Node* doSomeWork( Node* other ) override;
};
```

The concept of dynamic_cast still applies within your doSomeWork() function, however since the implementation is done on a class by implementation there is no need for a switch statement! Doing it this way any derived class must declare and implement this function. Now if a specific derived type has no use for this function, you still must define it, but you would leave the contents of the body empty.